# Cannot POST to express server from domain with SSL on it

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, nginx

I have an existing ssl certificate through LetsEncrypt for my domain.  On the same server as my site I have an express app running at port :8080.  Before adding the SSL to the domain I was able to make requests to http://domainname:8080.com.  Now that the domain making the requests is https it obviously can't make those requests.  If I instead make requests to https://domainname:8080.com, I get no response and instead get a timeout error.

I have attempted to curl -X -POST on the server manually and it returns `(35) gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.` If I however run the same command pointing to the non https domain it executes correctly.  I also tried installing the https modules for express and pointing it to the same certs I'm using for the domain.  For all my effort I cannot get this to work.  What am I missing here?  I want to make requests to a port on the same server that is serving my app.

Comment: does the TLS/HTTPS setup bind to the same 8080 port?

Comment: I tried setting up the 8443 connection through the express https module.  Other than that attempt the express server runs on 8080.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a reverse proxy in my nginx site config from the domain to the ip address the express server was running on.  This solved all the issues I was having.